# jQuery explode animation not working

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-animate

The only thing that happens by using the code below is that the image disappears with no animation at all. Any hints?

```
var img1 = $('<img src="image' + num + '.jpg" />').css({"position": "absolute"});
var div = $('<div id="wtf">').css({
        "position": "absolute",                    
        "left": targetX-80,
        "top": targetY-112.5
    });


    setTimeout(function() {div.append(img1).hide().fadeIn(400);}, 500);


    setTimeout(function() {div.append(img1).hide("explode", { pieces: 16 }, 400);}, 800); //not working

    $(document.body).append(div);
```

Comment: Did you include jQuery UI? http://jqueryui.com/

Comment: Can you show a demo?  Otherwise, nothing to do here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the image is absolutely positioned inside the div, the div doesn't have a height so the animation runs but doesn't have a real effect. Add a height to the div and you'll see the animation.

```
var div = $('<div id="wtf">').css({
    "position": "absolute",     
    "height": 100,               
    "left": targetX-80,
    "top": targetY-112.5
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Cm5qD/

(As a side note, there's no reason to re-append the image in the second `setTimeout()`.)

Comment: your doing the same thing i am only i took out the timeout on the exploid

Comment: Nope. It's the div's height that does it. The timers don't enter into it in any way.

Answer (score 0):

Base jQuery does not include a `.hide()` which can take a "explode" as a first parameter.

If you are using the jQueryUI library you need to include it.

Comment: True, but not the cause of the problem.

Answer (score -2):

This is what you want put the call to explode in the call back of the fadein.. also you need to find the image not append it again.  http://jsfiddle.net/jxZAW/

```
var img1 = $('<img src="http://placekitten.com/200/200" />').css({"position": "absolute"});
var div = $('<div id="wtf">').css({
        "position": "absolute",                    
        "left": 200,
        "top": 200
    });


    div.append(img1).hide().fadeIn(400,function(){
        div.find('img').hide('explode', { "pieces":16 }, 600, function() { $(this).remove; });
    });

   $(document.body).append(div);
```

Comment: Care to explain why this would work if the original code doesn't?

Comment: This works only because you're applying the animation to the image, not the div. The original code works just as well if you apply the animation to the image: http://jsfiddle.net/kpSrR/

Comment: Synchronisity doesn't affect it; animations are put into queue if the previous one hasn't had time to complete.

Comment: Yes, if a) the image is and will always be the only content in the div and b) the div has no styling applied. Those are rather bold assumptions to make.